# Azure Pipeline Task (Pass or Fail) based on the output results

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I wanted to fail or continue to next task based on the output result that we get from the below logs.

**Can we store the details and do a check?**

If I have anywhere "Failed" text displayed in the output logs, then I should be able to fail the pipeline, if there is no "Failed" text then it needs to continue to next task, as seen in the below screenshot, I'm getting "Failed" text but the task is passed.

**NOTE: I'm doing a schema vaidation of files, based on the validation I'm printing the "Failed" or "Succeeded" text in the output logs.**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the state of your checks "Failed" or "Succeeded" with PowerShell script so just add exit status:

```
if ($myvalidation -eq "Failed")
{
    exit 1
}
```